# CB_SELECTSTRING is not working for Japanese item

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, automation, pinvoke

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, string wParam, string lParam);

 Private void GetSlecteITemIdex()
 {
       int _ComBoxHandle = System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.Current.NativeWindowHandle;
       int l_GETSelectedItem1 = SendMessage((IntPtr)l_ComBoxHandle, CB_SELECTSTRING, null, "英語");
         if (l_GETSelectedItem1 == -1)
                throw new Exception("Item not found.");
 }
```

Combo Image:
[image: ComboBox containing japanese item]

I want to get index of japanese item "英語" from combobox but its always giving index "-1" using above code same for english items its giving me correct index what additionally need to do get Japanese item index correctly.

Comment: Try declaring `SendMessage` as [`[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage) and pass `-1` for `wParam` as shown in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-selectstring).

Comment: @dbc This should be an answer. Works great, as far as I'm able to see: https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/3148d3518fb8fd48c843a9d709b8c6bf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-selectstring), the arguments for a `CB_SELECTSTRING` message are:

> - `wParam`: The zero-based index of the item preceding the first item to be searched...  If wParam is -1, the entire list is searched from the beginning.
> - `lParam`: A pointer to the null-terminated string that contains the characters for which to search. The search is not case sensitive, so this string can contain any combination of uppercase and lowercase letters.

Thus you should choose the following declaration for `SendMessage` from https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] 
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam)
```

Pass `-1` (rather than `null`) for the first argument to search from the beginning.

(Note that [`CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset) may be chosen also.  As explained in *[Charsets and marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/charset?view=netframework-4.8)*, `Auto` and `Unicode` both cause strings to be marshalled to `wchar_t` (UTF-16) on *Windows* and `char16_t` (UTF-16) on *.NET Core 2.2 and earlier on Unix*; they differ only on *.NET Core 3.0 and later and Mono on Unix* where `Auto` marshals strings to `char` (UTF-8).)

Comment: Why are you recommending `CharSet.Auto` as opposed to [`CharSet.Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset#fields)?

Comment: @IInspectable Does it really make a [difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/charset?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @IInspectable - From [Charsets and marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/charset?view=netframework-4.8), `Auto` resolves to `wchar_t` (UTF-16) on Windows and .NET Core 2.2 and earlier on Unix but resolves to `char` (UTF-8) on .NET Core 3.0 and later and Mono on Unix.  So maybe the recommendation from pinvoke.net is obsolete... only for .Net Core 3.0 and later on Mono and Unix.  But does winforms even exist there?  I don't know enough to about that platform to recommend a change to the pinvoke.net recommendation.

Comment: @def: It does. One is explicit (and incidentally matches `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)`), the other is what's commonly referred to as *"code by coincidence"*. The latter increases the mental load on readers of the code. This is diametrical to what code should be.

Comment: @dbc: You aren't targeting Windows Forms. *user32.dll* is part of the Windows API surface. The Windows API is not available on *nix or macOS.